# How to apply filter while indexing Sitecore contacts

Tags: indexing

We would like to apply custom filters while `indexing Contacts in Sitecore`. How can we apply filters on `Mongo Data` so that only specific contacts will get indexed

Comment: Which version of Sitecore?

Comment: 8.2 Initial version

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code that decides if a contact should be indexed is defined in the `contacts` pipeline in the `analytics.aggregation` pipeline group. Specifically, the default processor is `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Aggregators.ContactChangeContactAggregator`, which just checks `contact.ShouldBeIndexed()`, which in turn just checks if it is an anonymous contact, and if it is, whether anonymous contacts should be indexed. If you would like to add more complex logic, you should override this processor with a custom implementation and then patch in your own processor.

Comment: Thanks. I am able to add filter but contact which does not have Lease.Owner.Type are not getting indexed. I am getting null exception for those contacts. Please note we have migrated contact from External System to MongoDB.